Need to calculate distinct count and percentage in a single row using power bi dax
I have below table in power bi.



id
name
date




1
A
30-April-2023


2
A
30-April-2023


1
A
30-April-2023


4
A
30-April-2023


3
B
30-April-2023


I
B
30-April-2023



I need a pivot table visual like motioned below.



.
A
B




A
3
1/2(50%)


B
1/2(50%)
2



example if A to A total distinct ID count is 3, and A to B is one part is shared among total parts of of b which is 1/2 nothing but 50%
This used to happen based user selection in slicer which is date.
How to this in DAX?

What is the formula/logic A:B? How did you get the result 1/2(50%)?

basically we need to display percentage, logic is, number of distinct shared IDS/Total distinct IDS ,In this case the total distinct shared IDS is 1 with compare to A (id 1 is present in A as well as in B) and Total distinct IDS for B is 2, hence 1/2 which is 50%. Please let me know if it is any confusing.

id 2 is also present in A and B. Why we don't count that?

My bad, I have edited from 2 to 3 in question, Sorry for confusion.

you can try this

create a new table
Table 2=
VAR _tbla =
DISTINCT ( 'Table'[name] )
VAR _tblb =
SELECTCOLUMNS ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[name] ), "name1", 'Table'[name] )
RETURN
CROSSJOIN ( _tbla, _tblb )

create a Column
Column=
VAR _list =
DISTINCT (
SELECTCOLUMNS (
FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[name] = 'Table 2'[name] ),
"id", 'Table'[id]
)
)
VAR _list2 =
DISTINCT (
SELECTCOLUMNS (
FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[name] = 'Table 2'[name1] ),
"id", 'Table'[id]
)
)
VAR _count =
COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( _list, _list2 ) )
RETURN
IF (
'Table 2'[name] = 'Table 2'[name1],
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[id] ),
FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[name] = 'Table 2'[name] )
),
_count
/ CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[id] ),
FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[name] = 'Table 2'[name] )
)
)



then you can create a matrix


Thanks a lot, This working perfectly, when I am passing slicer value to newly created column then it is not working. Still struggling to make above DAX dynamic. Request you to help me on this please.

my slicer value is date column

I have changed the code like blow:
Table 2= VAR _tbla = DISTINCT ( 'Table'[name] )
VAR _tbld = DISTINCT ( 'Table'[date]  )
VAR _tblb = SELECTCOLUMNS ( DISTINCT ( 'Table'[name] ), "name1", 'Table'[name] )
RETURN CROSSJOIN ( _tbla, _tblb ,_tbld )

Column =
VAR _list = DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Derivate] = 'Table 2'[Derivate] && 'Table'[date] = 'Table 2'[date] ), "id", 'Table'[PartNumber] ) )
VAR _list2 = DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Derivate] = 'Table 2'[Derivate1] && 'Table'[date] = 'Table 2'[date]  ), "id", 'Table'[PartNumber] ) )
VAR _count = COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( _list, _list2 ) )

continued,
RETURN
IF ( 'Table 2'[Derivate] = 'Table 2'[Derivate1], CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[PartNumber] ),
FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Derivate] = 'Table 2'[Derivate] && 'Table'[date] = 'Table 2'[date]  ) ),
_count / CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[PartNumber] ), FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Derivate] = 'Table 2'[Derivate] && 'Table'[date] = 'Table 2'[date] ) ) )

Now working, Thanks a lot.
